# XMPP and Android Part-2

Tags: java, android, xmpp, xmppframework, asmack

This question is continuation of my previous question though i have managed to remove the NetworkOnMainThreadError, now i have new errors to fight with,

Previous question can be found here: [XMPP and ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223022/xmpp-and-android)

This time i guess the probelm is with my host name, or may be service name, i am trying to connect to `openFire` server.

By the way do i need to add `public class SettingsDialog extends Dialog` into Menifest file

**My code for connection:**

```
/**
 * Gather the xmpp settings and create an XMPPConnection
 */
public class SettingsDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    private XMPPClient xmppClient;

    public SettingsDialog(XMPPClient xmppClient) {
        super(xmppClient);
        this.xmppClient = xmppClient;
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        getWindow().setFlags(4, 4);
        setTitle("XMPP Settings");
        Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


        public void onClick(View v) {

            new NetworkOperation().execute();
            dismiss();
        }
```

**Async Task**

```
public class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private XMPPClient xmppClient;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String host = "web.vlivetech.com"; //getText(R.id.host);
        String port = "5222";  //getText(R.id.port);
        String service = "web.vlivetech.com"; //getText(R.id.service);
        String username = "khubaib@web.vlivetech.com"; //getText(R.id.userid);
        String password = "khubaib"; //getText(R.id.password);

        // Create a connection
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port),service);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            // Set the status to available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
  }
```

**Line on which i am getting an error in Async Task:**

```
try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
```

**Log File**

```
03-06 17:50:39.754: I/SmackConfiguration(16410): No configuration file found
03-06 17:50:39.764: E/XMPPClient(16410): [SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to null
03-06 17:50:39.764: W/dalvikvm(16410): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aaa210)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at com.example.test.NetworkOperation.doInBackground(NetworkOperation.java:33)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at com.example.test.NetworkOperation.doInBackground(NetworkOperation.java:1)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-06 17:50:39.774: E/AndroidRuntime(16410):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: I guess you are getting "connection == null".

Comment: why am i getting it? is there any problem with my host name? or port or something else?

Comment: May be yes, you can debug and check whether you are getting host name null or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your `NetworkOperation` is inside your activity then remove this line from `NetworkOperation` or you might want to add a `constructor`(?), pass the `xmppClient` with the `.execute()`

```
private XMPPClient xmppClient;
```

Comment: sorry i missed that, inside the async task? where??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use from this code .. and you don't need to AsyncTask ..

```
 String HOST = "Yourhost";
        int PORT = your port;
        String USERNAME = "USERNAME";
        String PASSWORD = "YOURPASSWORD";


            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                            HOST, PORT);
                    connConfig.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
                    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
                    try {
                        connection.connect();
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Connected to " + connection.getHost());


                    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                                + connection.getHost());
                        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());


                    }
                    try {

                        connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                                "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());


                        // Set the status to available
                        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                        connection.sendPacket(presence);

                        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

                    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                                + USERNAME);
                        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());


                    }

                }
            });
            t.start();
```